# Insert string into specific part of another string

Tags: php, string

I've got a URL as a string, for example:

```
http://example.com/sub/sub2/hello/
```

I'd like to add another subfolder to it with PHP, before `hello`, so it should look like this:

```
http://example.com/sub/sub2/sub3/hello/
```

I thought about using explode to separate the URL by slashes, and adding another one before the last one, but I'm pretty sure I over complicate it. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Am I the only one how don't see any differences between both strings?

Comment: @Rizier123 I am too with you. :)

Comment: oh, sorry guys, updated my question :)

Comment: So now it's the question where and how do you want to define where you include the sub folder? (I mean is it always before the last folder where you want to add a folder or is it every time after the second folder where you want to add another one?)

Comment: I want to add a third subfolder before the last folder (the last folder is `hello`) in the easiest way possible. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just put the extra folder between the [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and the [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) of the string so that it is right before the last part of your url)

```
<?php

    $str = "http://example.com/sub/sub2/hello/";
    $folder = "sub3";

    echo dirname($str) . "/$folder/" . basename($str);

?>
```

output:

```
http://example.com/sub/sub2/sub3/hello
```

Answer (score 1):

If your url has this specific format you can use this:

```
$main_url = 'http://example.com/sub/sub2/';
$end_url_part = 'hello/';
$subfolder = 'sub3/';

if (isset($subfolder)) {
    return $main_url.$subfolder.$end_url_part;
} else {
   return $main_url.$end_url_part;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode`, `splice`, `implode`:

```
$str = "http://example.com/sub/sub2/hello/";
$str_arr = explode('/', $str);
array_splice($str_arr, -2, 0, 'sub3');
$str_new = implode('/', $str_arr);
// http://example.com/sub/sub2/sub3/hello/
```